# tableView data source empty in viewDidLoad() - Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

Below is my ViewController code. The println in GetRequest prints the correct data that it receives from the HTTP GET request. At this point, tableData has 10 key-value pairs. However, if I put a break point after the call to GetRequest() in viewDidLoad(), tableData is empty and nothing is displayed in the tableView. Why is this? Where am I going wrong?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource
{
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    var tableData: [String:String] = [:]
    let textCellIdentifier = "TextCell"

func GetRequest(urlPath: String)
{
    var LatestWaitTimes: [String:String] = [:]
    let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in

        if error != nil {
            // If there is an error in the web request, print it to the console
            println(error.localizedDescription)
        }

        var err: NSError?
        var jsonResult: AnyObject? = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err)
        if err != nil {
            // If there is an error parsing JSON, print it to the console
            println("JSON Error \(err!.localizedDescription)")
        }

        let json = JSON(jsonResult!)
        let count: Int? = json.array?.count

        if let ct = count {
            for index in 0...ct-1 {
                let name = json[index]["CrossingName"].string
                var wait = json[index]["WaitTime"].stringValue
                if (wait == "-1")
                {
                    wait = "No Info"
                }
                else
                {
                    wait += " min"
                }
                println(name!+": "+wait)
                LatestWaitTimes[json[index]["CrossingName"].stringValue] = wait as String?
            }
        }
        self.tableData = LatestWaitTimes
    })
    task.resume()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var apiInfo = GetWaitTimes()
    GetRequest(apiInfo.BorderCrossingApi+"?AccessCode="+apiInfo.AccessCode)
    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.reloadData()
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1;
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return tableData.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(self.textCellIdentifier) as! UITableViewCell
    let thisEntry = self.tableData.values.array[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = thisEntry+": "+tableData[thisEntry]!
    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
}
}
```

Comment: Unrelated, but I might suggest a different method name for `GetRequest`. Usually we start method names with lower case letters. Perhaps `requestWaitTimesFromURL` or something like that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `GetRequest` runs asynchronously. So you have to `reloadData` inside the `completionHandler` of `dataTaskWithURL`:

```
let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in

    // do all of your existing stuff here

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.tableData = LatestWaitTimes
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
})
task.resume()
```

You can remove the `reloadData` from within `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: I made this change. However, in my TableViewDataSource methods, return tableData.count returns 0 and then the line var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(self.textCellIdentifier) as! UITableViewCell throws an error as the object is nil

Comment: Then I would suggest debugging the code that's parsing the response and make sure that parsing is happening correctly. Put a breakpoint inside that `completionHandler` and examine the data you retrieved. (Also remember that the data source methods will actually get called twice, once when the view is first loaded (and before there is any data to display) and then again when the request finishes. We're concerned that your code to parse the response is working correctly.

Comment: Fair enough. I'll do that. Thanks!

Comment: @Rob don't you think that `@escaping` would be needed here? :)

Answer (score 0):

Rearrange the orders of the method calls:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    var apiInfo = GetWaitTimes()
    GetRequest(apiInfo.BorderCrossingApi+"?AccessCode="+apiInfo.AccessCode)
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Explanation: you set the delegate and dataSource before you GetRequest() so the dataSource won't be nil.

Comment: Rearranged, and still no change

Comment: @wemblem While Schemetrical is correct that it's prudent to set your `delegate` and `dataSource` earlier in the process, that's not the problem here. The main problem is that you're calling `reloadData` on the main thread, immediately after issuing the asynchronous request, but that request won't retrieve the data until later. So, you have to move the `reloadData` call inside that `completionHandler` closure where you're parsing the JSON and the like. And remember to do it on the main thread.

Comment: @Rob oh, I didn't realise that GetRequest was async i this case. Upvoted yours for visibility.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it may help you

you can add a callback (for reload tablview) in `GetRequest` function and run the callback  after parser json in `completionHandler`

Maybe When you set the delegate with tableview, tableData still be nil (waitting for http response)

this is my code .you can refer to

```
demand.loadDataFromServer(self.view, done: { () -> Void in
     self.demands = demand.getDemandDataList()
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
         self.tableView.reloadData()
     })
})


func loadDataFromServer(view:UIView,done:(() -> Void)!){
    var request:HttpRequest = HttpRequest(view:view)
    request.GET(getDemandListURL, parameters: nil, success: { (dict) -> Void in
        self.demandLists = dict["data"] as NSMutableArray
        done()
        }, failed: { (dict) -> Void in

        }) { (error) -> Void in
    }
}
```